# help with javascript function

Tags: javascript, radio-button

I have a requirement below and I am struggling with javascript,

In a table I am showing different plans(Medical, Dental, Vision , there can be multiple plans ..I mean Medical 1, Medical 2, Dental 1, Dental 2) and for each plan I am showing radio buttons to either select that plan or waive that plan. Based on their selection, I need to update the amount the people will be paying. So if they select "waive" , the amount would be updated to ZERO. If they select "Select" option, according to plan rate, their amount would be updated. At one time, they can select only one type of a plan.

```
 Plan        Option                                  Amount
 Medical_1   RadioButton_Elect/RadioButton_Waive     $0.00
 Medical_2   RadioButton_Elect/RadioButton_Waive     $5.00
```

My problem is with naming those radiobuttons so that user can select only one option at a time. I can name them same and they can be mutually exclusive, but my javascript function to update the amount doesn't update the value correctly then.

```
function updateAmount(){
  if(document.getElementById('waive0').checked == 'true'){
     document.planselect.planeecost0.value = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: You have a bug in your updated function, but unless you share the code, we can't help you.

Comment: I added the code which you people wanted to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A radio button group is defined by radio buttons that have the same name. The obvious consequence is that you cannot use the `name` attribute to tell them out. You need to use something else. Your options include:

- Read the `value` tag.
- Set a different `id` tag for each button.
- Identify buttons by their position in the DOM tree.

If unsure, you can go for the `id` approach, though the `value` approach is also a valid option.

Comment: I liked your suggestion and I will be trying that.

Comment: I will for sure. But I tried writing my function using what you suggested, but it is not working. Basically it is not updating the value.